# Split the value in table column sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Table name: `Table1`

The table has 2 columns

```
Id   Name

1     1|admin|abs@yahoo.com
2     22|user|aaaaa@yahoo.com
```

From the `Name` column I want to fetch the email adress

Result:

```
Name
abs@yahoo.com    
aaaaa@yahoo.com
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL: Opposite to string concatenation - how to split string into multiple records](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-recor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
select SUBSTRING(name,CHARINDEX('|',name, CHARINDEX('|', name)+1)+1,100) from  Table1
```